# How do I retrieve error details when Saxon XSLT transformation fails?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, saxon

I am using Saxon 9 HE 9.7.0.7 for .NET. Typically, when I run XsltTransformer.Run, the DomDestination.XmlDocument property will be populated. However, with some documents, that property will be null. When the property is null, I am assuming that some kind of error was encountered, but no exceptions are thrown, and I'm not seeing any errors on the console. How can I retrieve details regarding why the transformation failed?

For one such example document, I tried the transform from the command line and it completed without any issue.

Here is some example code. The destination.XmlDocument property on the last line will sometimes be null.

```
        // Compile stylesheet
        var processor = new Processor();
        var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
        var executable = compiler.Compile(new Uri(xsltFilePath));
        var declaredArgs = executable.GetGlobalParameters();

        // Do transformation to a destination
        var destination = new DomDestination();
        using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xml.Save(inputStream);
            inputStream.Position = 0;
            var transformer = executable.Load();
            transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(inputXmlFileInfo.DirectoryName));
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                var matchingArgDeclaration = declaredArgs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key.LocalName.ToLower() == arg.Key.ToLower());
                if (matchingArgDeclaration.Key == null)
                {
                    transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(arg.Value));
                }
                else
                {
                    // try to load up the specific parameter type
                    // list is based on http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!dotnetdoc/Saxon.Api/XdmAtomicValue
                    XdmItemType argType = matchingArgDeclaration.Value.getDeclaredItemType();
                    var argTypeName = "";
                    if (argType != null &&
                        argType is XdmAtomicType)
                        argTypeName = ((XdmAtomicType)argType).Name.LocalName;
                    switch (argTypeName.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "boolean":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(Convert.ToBoolean(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "integer":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(Convert.ToInt32(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "decimal":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(Convert.ToDecimal(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "float":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(Convert.ToSingle(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "double":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(Convert.ToDouble(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "anyuri":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(new Uri(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        case "qname":
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(new QName(arg.Value)));
                            break;

                        default:
                            transformer.SetParameter(new QName(arg.Key), new XdmAtomicValue(((arg.Value))));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            transformer.Run(destination);
        }

        // Save result to a file (or whatever else you wanna do)
        destination.XmlDocument.Save(outputFileName);
```

Comment: Can you post minimal but complete samples of XML and XSLT to demonstrate the problem? What is the output on the command line, a well-formed document or a fragment? A DomDestination with the default constructor will only be able to store a well-formed document I think, not a fragment, so one guess would be your XSLT creates a fragment with several top level elements or no root element at all.

Comment: Ugh. This doesn't directly answer my question in the way that I asked it, but it turns out that the stylesheet is outputting to a file using xsl:result-document, which is way i was getting a null XmlDocument property. If someone wants to answer explaining how errors are typically reported from transformer.Run, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of error: static errors and dynamic errors.

Static errors (for example, syntax errors, or use of an undeclared variable or function) are added to the `ErrorList` property of the `XsltCompiler`. The `Compile()` method will throw an exception, and you should then check the details in the ErrorList for detailed diagnostics.

Dynamic errors (for example divide by zero) result in the `XsltTransformer.Run()` method throwing an exception of class `Saxon.Api.DynamicError`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the stylesheet that I had been given was trying to output to a file using xsl:result-document. As a result, the XmlDocument property was null and no errors were thrown.

Per the [documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XsltTransformer.html#Run(Saxon.Api.XmlDestination)), when executing transformer.Run, errors should typically be thrown as a DynamicError exception.